# Alignment / matching problem with groups

Tags: r, manova

I have two data sets (`base` and `to_match`), each with 10 individuals, grouped in 2 classes. Each individual is described by a set of 4 variables.

What I want to do is:

1. test wether the groups in the first dataset (`base`) are identical, based on all the describing variables
2. for each group in the second dataset (`to_match`) find the best matching group in the first dataset (`base`).

So far, what I did, was to perform a MANOVA within the first dataset, to determine if the groups were identical or not.

Then, I did a Linear Discriminant Analysis on the first group and used the resulting model to predict, for each individual of the second dataset, what was the closest group in the first dataset.

The `base` dataset looks like this

```
Group   A   B   C   D
1   0.457713143 -0.961504141    0.569530865 -0.467462304
1   -0.636764605    -0.695107438    0.210832138 -0.602475976
1   -1.216053575    0.647085589 0.42723523  0.024371887
1   -1.143872508    -0.771171997    1.610054266 0.862983524
1   -0.947740051    -0.96552701 -0.528481972    -0.157774001
2   -0.446452415    -0.555949371    -0.392508973    -0.465565853
2   1.143621911 -0.083821489    -1.174028532    -0.307616562
2   -0.118523439    2.250822002 -0.423022806    -0.342627702
2   -0.119453796    2.251860651 -0.460992853    -0.412183789
2   -1.119923882    0.945486343 1.269202026 -1.005019157
```

The `to_match`dataset looks like this:

```
Group   A   B   C   D
1   0.778450123 -1.245864489    -0.688726943    -0.365538752
1   -1.177318015    0.059801545 0.259885094 0.453012798
1   -1.442516109    -0.422214798    -0.563490254    0.12831251
1   -0.639054602    -0.290063747    -1.249974299    1.473130636
1   -0.334179518    -1.006135106    0.30382184  2.093512163
2   -0.441086171    -0.494222266    -0.346210044    -0.394250031
2   -0.426666213    -0.444327313    -0.350570961    -0.437023047
2   0.382495524 -1.716667725    -1.040363139    0.544599656
2   -0.51828116 -0.757302352    -0.2163689  0.776728601
2   -0.497205151    -0.364979901    -0.632382926    0.222393228
```

What I have done so far:

```
library(MASS)

# Load Datasets
base  <- read.table("base.txt", header = T)
to_match  <- read.table("to_match.txt", header = T)

# MANOVA analysis
fit <- manova(cbind(A, B, C, D) ~ Group,  base) # Stele was removed
summary(fit)

# LDA analysis
fit <- lda(Group ~ ., data=base, CV=F)

# Predict the class of each individual from the to_match dataset
fit.p <- predict(fit, newdata = to_match[,-1])
```

So what I have been able to do so far is to match individuals from the `to_match`dataset to group in the `base` dataset using the `lda` and `predict` functions from the `MASS`package.

What I would like to do is **not the match individuals, but the groups directly**. Is this possible?

Comment: So, your output looks like, say, base.A = to_match.B, base.B = to_match.D, and so on?

Comment: So practically you know that the discrimination in the `to_match` dataset has been done correctly but you are unsure if you confused the labels of the groups in this dataset?

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch @user1669710 Well, what I want to do is to know if the group 1 in `to_match` is more closely related to group 1 or group 2 in `base`.

Comment: @Wiliam: In this case I would rather use some descriptive statistic, e.g. something like Mahalanobis-Distance (of couse taking into account that the 4 groups might have different covariance matrices each), like "Is the group mean of group1 (to_match) closer to group1 (base) or group2 (base)?" The correct procedure is heavily dependent on the application context.